# Access 2010 - Macro to set dropdowns to preset fields

Tags: macros, microsoft-access, hotkeys

I work with a form in Access daily in which I repeatedly have to type the same words into the same fields. I would like to automate this (those fields auto-fill to predetermined text when I press a hotkey) using the macro builder.

My knowledge of Access macros is all of 3 intro videos I've watched so far. If someone could point out/direct me to the proper resources to learn a) what actions I should be looking at and b) methods to trigger with a keystroke from the form view (ex. Ctrl+Q or something) I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need macro for that.

What you need convert your field to combo-box if it isn't that yet, set the source data correctly, than set `auto expand` property to `true`. It won't work with the hotkey, but automatically fill your data when you start typing.

If you really prefer hotkeys then you can find help how to set them [here](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Run-an-Access-macro-by-using-a-keyboard-shortcut-0d267570-d3da-46eb-9bfb-a3c81af676be), the macro will contain something like this: `activecontrol.value={yourvalue}`